# Min Max with IDs - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to get this output in Oracle 8i:

```
column1 |time
________|_______
  ABC   | 00:00:01
  END   | 00:00:03
  123   | 00:00:04
  END   | 00:00:07
  ABC   | 00:00:08
  END   | 00:00:10
```

with this output from another query

```
   column1  |time       |ID
    ________|___________|
      ABC   | 00:00:01  |  1
      ABC   | 00:00:02  |  1
      ABC   | 00:00:03  |  1 
      123   | 00:00:04  |  1
      123   | 00:00:05  |  1
      123   | 00:00:06  |  1
      123   | 00:00:07  |  1
      ABC   | 00:00:08  |  2
      ABC   | 00:00:09  |  2
      ABC   | 00:00:10  |  2
```

This query gets min and max without considering ID.

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then column1 else 'END' end) as column1,
       (case when n.n = 1 then firsttime else lasttime end) as "time"
from (select column1, min(time) as firsttime, max(time) as lasttime
      from t
      group by column1
     ) t cross join
     (select 1 as n from dual union all select 2 from dual) n
order by column1, n.n;
```

How to do the same thing but  instead of getting first and last value for occurences in column1, consider ID as well?

Comment: replace `GROUP BY column1` by `GROUP BY column1, id`?

Comment: I think you want `order by t.firsttime, t.column1, n.n` as well to keep the adjacent values together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `id` in the logic, both in the `group by` and in the `order by`:

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then column1 else 'END' end) as column1,
       (case when n.n = 1 then firsttime else lasttime end) as "time"
from (select column1, id, min(time) as firsttime, max(time) as lasttime
      from t
      group by column1, id
     ) t cross join
     (select 1 as n from dual union all select 2 from dual) n
order by id, column1, n.n;
```

Comment: So as I add new columns that group the result I add them in the group ny and order by? What is the correct order of them? For example if I had another level of grouping the values I'd add the column adter column1?

Comment: @Dalek . . . The order of columns in the `group by` doesn't make a difference.